# How to issue a delete request in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my rails app, I have a following link:

```
<%= link_to("Log out", logout_path, method: :delete)%>
```

And in my routes I added:

```
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

However, when I click on the Log out link, I get the following routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/logout"
```

It seems that even I specified "method: :delete", the "link_to" function still issues a get request instead of a delete request.
How do I send a delete request with ruby on rails?

My application.js looks like this:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Can you post the `application.js` to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually occurs due to a missing JS dependency in `application.js`.

If you're using Rails 5, add:

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

And for earlier versions ensure you have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

In there.

The reason for this is that a little Rails magic 'fakes' the delete request as most browsers don't support this. It will add `data-method="delete"` to your HTML tag, allowing your application to recognise the request as it should be, and process as `DELETE` (even though it's *actually* sent as a `GET` request).

Also, ensure you're loading said Javascript via the following line in your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Let me know how you get on or if you have any questions - hope this helps.

Comment: I have all the requires in the application.js. My generated HTML has the line to be :"<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a>". And the problem presists

Comment: Ah, shame. Do you see any errors in your JS console when you load the page?

Comment: I finally find the bug. I did not include the js file properly, and I have both bootstrap and bootstrap-sass in Gemfile and they caused some strange bug. Thanks.